# How to switch the current goal in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is it possible to switch the current goal or subgoal to prove in Coq?

For example, I have a goal like this (from an eexists):

```
______________________________________(1/1)
?s > 0 /\ r1 * (r1 + s1) + ?s = r3 * (r3 + s2)
```

What I want to do is to `split` and prove the right conjunct first. This I think will give the value of the existential variable `?s`, and the left conjunct should be just a simplification away.

But `split` by default set the left conjunct `?s > 0` as the current goal.

```
______________________________________(1/2)
?s > 0
______________________________________(2/2)
r1 * (r1 + s1) + ?s = r3 * (r3 + s2)
```

I know I can prefix tactics with `2:` to operate on the second subgoal, but it's awkward because

1) I can't see the hypotheses for goal#2 and

2) if it's in a different context, goal#2 might be the third or the k_th goal. The proof won't be portable.

That's why I want to set the second goal as the current.

BTW, I am using CoqIDE (8.5).

Comment: fyi, `The Focus command is deprecated; use '2: {' instead [deprecated-focus,deprecated]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `Focus 2` to focus on the second goal.

Comment: `The Focus command is deprecated; use '2: {' instead [deprecated-focus,deprecated]`

Answer (score 3):

Update from 2021: use `2:`.

`Focus 2` is deprecated at least since 8.13:

```
The Focus command is deprecated; use '2: {' instead [deprecated-focus,deprecated]
```

Comment: sorry what is the command we need to use?

Comment: @CharlieParker you actually write `2: {` as a "tactic".