# How to leave a goal unfinished in Coq

Tags: coq

In Isabelle, you can leave a goal unfinished in two ways:

- sorry: will leave your proof and the fact can be used in later proofs.
- oops: will leave the proof but the fact cannot be used in later proofs.

Is there similar functionality in Coq that would allow me to leave a goal unfinished to come back later to it? This is useful to sketch the structure of the proof while not filling in all the details. Note that the approach in [How to switch the current goal in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421064/how-to-switch-the-current-goal-in-coq) modifies the proof structure. That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791453/coq-admit-assert

Answer (score 4):

You have several ways to terminate a proof in Coq. You probably know `Qed` which asserts the proof is completed. There is also `Defined` for when you want the proof to have computational content.

The things you are looking for are:

- `Admitted` which admits the proof, so it can be used later;
- `Abort` which gives up on proving the lemma.

They can be used that way:

```
Lemma foo : forall n, n = 0.
Proof.
  intro n. destruct n.
  - reflexivity.
  -
Abort.
```

```
Lemma bar : forall n, n = n.
Admitted.
```

In both cases you can have a partial proof script before the `Admitted`/`Abort` or none at all.

As @HTNW points out, you can also use the equivalent tactics `admit` and `give_up` inside subgoals of the proof. Using those, the proof however *has* to be concluded using either `Admitted` or `Abort`.

```
Lemma lem : forall A, A + A -> A.
Proof.
  intros A h.
  destruct h.
  - admit.
  - give_up.
Admitted.
```

The partial proof is in any case thrown away with this solution.
If for some reason you want to keep using a partial proof (for instance if you want to compute with it), a common trick is to use an axiom to close the goals that you want to leave for later.

```
Axiom cheating : forall A, A.

Tactic Notation "cheat" := apply cheating.

Lemma lem : forall A, A + A -> A.
Proof.
  intros A h.
  destruct h.
  - cheat.
  - cheat.
Defined. (* This is now ok *)
```

You have to be careful using that trick though. You can check that a lemma has been proven without axioms using `Print Assumptions lem`. If it says "closed under context" you're good, otherwise it will lists the axioms it depends on and if `cheating` appears you know it's not entirely proven.

Comment: There's also the tactic `admit`/`give_up`. This admits a single subgoal inside a proof instead of admitting the whole thing.

Comment: Right, but if you do it then you have to conclude using `Admitted` or `Abort` anyway. But if you don't mind I will add it to my answer.